# Caught KeyError while rendering: 'phone_mobile'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

forms.py

```
class UserCreateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone_daytime = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    phone_mobile = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['phone_daytime', 'phone_mobile']
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
    phone_daytime = cleaned_data.get('phone_daytime')
    phone_mobile = cleaned_data.get('phone_mobile')

    if not any([phone_daytime, phone_mobile]):
        self._errors['phone_daytime'] = self.error_class(['Enter a valid phone number'])
        del self.cleaned_data['phone_daytime']
        self._errors['phone_mobile'] = self.error_class(['Enter a valid phone number'])
        del self.cleaned_data['phone_mobile']
    return cleaned_data
```

template.py

```
 <tr>
     <td>Daytime phone:</td><td>{{ form.phone_daytime }}{{ form.phone_daytime.errors }}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>Mobile phone:</td><td>{{ form.phone_mobile }}{{ form.phone_mobile.errors }}</td>
  </tr>
```

I am getting this error "`Caught KeyError while rendering: 'phone_mobile'`" when i enter some character in "phone_daytime" field.Appart from all other validations are working.

Please see my complete traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.100.10/member/about-me/

Django Version: 1.3.7
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'collect',
 'incident']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware')


Template error:
In template /root/Projects/ir/templates/incident/about_me.html, error at line 332
   Caught KeyError while rendering: 'phone_mobile'
   322 :                             <table  width="100%">


   323 :                                 <tr>


   324 :                                     <td></td><td>*  Mandatory Fields</td></tr>


   325 :                                 <tr>


   326 :                                     <td style="width:100px;">First name:</td><td>{{registerform.first_name|capfirst}}*{{registerform.first_name.errors}}</td>


   327 :                                 </tr>


   328 :                                 <tr>


   329 :                                     <td>Last name:</td><td>{{registerform.last_name}}*{{registerform.last_name.errors}}</td>


   330 :                                 </tr>


   331 :                                 <tr>


   332 :                                     <td>Daytime phone:</td><td>{{createprofile.phone_daytime|default:""}} {{createprofile.phone_daytime.errors }} </td>


   333 :                                 </tr>


   334 :                                 <tr>


   335 :                                     <td>Mobile phone:</td><td>{{createprofile.phone_mobile|safe}}{{createprofile.phone_mobile.errors }}</td>


   336 :                                 </tr>


   337 :                                 <tr>


   338 :                                     <td>Email:</td><td>{{registerform.email}}*{{registerform.email.errors }}</td>


   339 :                                 </tr>


   340 :                                 <tr>


   341 :                                     <td>User name</td><td>{{registerform.username}}*{{registerform.username.errors }}</td>


   342 :                                 </tr>


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/root/Projects/ir/incident/decorators.py" in wrapper
  17.             return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/root/Projects/ir/incident/views.py" in about_me
  408.                    'is_member_screen':is_member_screen
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  44.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  188.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  123.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  127.         return compiled_parent._render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  117.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  64.             result = block.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  744.                 bits.append(self.render_node(node, context))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  73.             result = node.render(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py" in render
  90.             output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  510.                 obj = self.var.resolve(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in resolve
  653.             value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _resolve_lookup
  683.                         current = getattr(current, bit)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _errors
  415.         return self.form.errors.get(self.name, self.form.error_class())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _get_errors
  112.             self.full_clean()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in full_clean
  268.         self._clean_form()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py" in _clean_form
  296.             self.cleaned_data = self.clean()
File "/root/Projects/ir/incident/forms.py" in clean
  183.             del self.cleaned_data['phone_mobile']

Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError at /member/about-me/
Exception Value: Caught KeyError while rendering: 'phone_mobile'
```

Actually it should through error message since ,both `phone_daytime` and `phone_mobile` are declared as `IntegerField`.But this giving the above error.Need help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Deleting` the below line cleared the above error and `validation` also working without issue

```
 del self.cleaned_data['']
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Its  because when you dont enter anything in phone_mobile it will not exists in cleaned_data and you are trying to delete it from there so you will get this error

Comment: sorry,the error is happening when i enter some "string" in field and press save,if i don't enter anything in phone_mobile field,it is showing the validation error.

Comment: @user2086641, The answer is correct. Even when data in the field is not valid it will not be set in `form.cleaned_data`. You should check if its there in the dict, then only delete/access it.

Comment: As  Rohan said, before deleting you need to check if it exists in the dictionary and only then do something with it